# The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten

Tags: typescript

I am using [microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle) to build the public typescript lib , when I using this `npm run build` command to build the lib,show info like this:

```
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
```

where is the problem about these info? what should I do to fix it? I have searched the whole project, and found nowhere defined the `this` keywords.

Comment: What specific tool in the build process is showing you that message? Does it really not give you any information about where the `this` it's referring to is?

Comment: yes, these compile log did not show which tool give this message, I have no clue to found out where is the problem.

Comment: I don't think it's a *problem*. It's just notifying you of a transformation it's made in the code.

Comment: but these tips are noising, I want to make the code clean and compile without any warning or noise.